# Can not "see" work pc's when connected on VPN from my home

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop

I have created a VPN connection (my router at my work office allowed could do this) from my home pc to my work office.  When I connect to my work VPN all seems great as my IP address changes to the static IP of my work and not my local IP from home.

My problem is that when I run the following command to show all the office PCs it returns nothing.  (There are 10 working PCs in my small office)

```
sudo arp-scan -l
```

This means that when I want to "rdesktop" into one of these computers, I can not.  Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: The router might not be configured to forward ARP packets across the VPN. Can you use rdesktop with an IP address? You will need to use tcpdump or wireshark to diagnose exactly what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem had to do with routing all the broadcast traffic (a design to keep bandwidth use down), so you don’t see the “here I am” broadcasts that say PCXXX is on the network.

However, if you know the IP address of the PC that you want to connect to, you should be able to ping it and do whatever you need to.

After I noticed that, I tried to ping the work office PCs from my home pc.  It turns out that I could ping them, but I could not log into the PC.  This was for two reasons:

1.) First was that I had not set static IPs for the PCs in the office workplace.  So each time the office PC was rebooted, it was assigned a new IP address.  Once this was fixed I could at least make sure that the PC I was trying to sign into was indeed the correct PC
2.) The second issue was that "Standard User" account under Windows 7 does NOT allow a connect to RDP.  I had to do two steps to fix this
2a) Temporarily change the "Standard Account" to an "Admin Account"
2b) Then add that user to the accounts that can RDP into